# Concatenation of variable not working with SQL command in PowerShell script

Tags: sql, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to get the value of a date variable into the string by concat

```
 $Lastextracteddate=Get-ChildItem $folder |
    Select-Object @{Name="LastWriteTime";
    Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}} | Select -LAST 1 | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
    
    $queryresult="select count(1) from user_table  WHERE replace(convert(varchar,[CREATE_S],112),'/','') +
    replace(convert(varchar,[CREATE_S],108),':','')>'$Lastextracteddate'"
   echo $Lastextracteddate
   echo $queryresult
```

I tried to pass the variable as above. Also tried to pass without single quote but no luck.
Getting result as below. Need help on this topic.

PS C:\Users> .\test.ps1

20231215191534

```
select count(1) from user_table  WHERE replace(convert(varchar,[CREATE_S],112),'/','') +
replace(convert(varchar,[CREATE_S],108),':','')>'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData'
```

Comment: Replace `... | Select -LAST 1 | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders` with `... | Select -Last 1 -Expand LastWriteTime`

Comment: Side notes: never use `varchar` without a length. If you have dates you should keep them as such, don't convert them to match a string.

Comment: @Charlieface, Thank you for the notes. Basically I have to get the dates from the file names and pass it to the query so , have to do like above.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you somuch. It's really helpful. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: You still don't need to convert the column. Instead get your parameter in the right format to compare to the column. You should really use proper parameterization anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following script, I eliminated the use of `Format-Table` (which outputs format data, not actual values) and directly extracted the last write time of the latest file in the desired format as a string, using `Select-Object -Last 1` and `ForEach-Object` to format the date, ensuring `$Lastextracteddate` correctly stores the date string for use in the SQL query. Try this

```
$Lastextracteddate = Get-ChildItem $folder |
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    ForEach-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") }

$queryresult = "select count(1) from user_table WHERE replace(convert(varchar,[CREATE_S],112),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar,[CREATE_S],108),':','') > '$Lastextracteddate'"

echo $Lastextracteddate
echo $queryresult
```

Comment: I want to convert the last extracteddate to UTC & I did something like this  $LastextracteddateUTC=$Lastextracteddate.TouniversalTime().ToString('yyyymmddHHmmss') but getting error does not contain method TouniversalTime. Any idea!

Comment: Got it. Please ignore,  above worked!  Some minor changes. Thanks all for your responses. Truly appreciate.